# Push key value pair to an existing object in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have a object and I want to add one more key value pair to that object, rather than declaring it inside the object declaration. I tried below code but it gives me an error like this.

> Property 'specialty' does not exist on type

```
saveFormData(value: any) {

    const saveData = {
          userPartyRoleId : Number(this.userPartyRoleId),
          notes : thihis.notes,
        };
    
    saveData.speciality = this.spec;
}
```

Comment: Use the spread operator and create a new object, both initial and new object will have correct typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a TypeScript feature. When you initialize `saveData` with a value, TypeScript implicitly infers that `saveData` must have only two properties: `userPartyRoleId`, `notes`, and nothing else.

To work around this, you have a few options I can think of.

#### Solution 1

The most straightforward solution. Just include `speciality` when initializing `saveData`. This assigns the correct type for `saveData`.

```typescript
const saveData = {
    userPartyRoleId: Number(this.userPartyRoleId),
    notes: this.notes,
    speciality: this.spec
};
```

#### Solution 2

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the spread operator. It will create a new object with the correct type, which you will want to assign to a different variable.

```typescript
const saveData = {
    userPartyRoleId: Number(this.userPartyRoleId),
    notes: this.notes
};

const processedData = {
    ...saveData,
    speciality: this.spec
};
```

#### Solution 3

This is a solution in a sense that it will make your code compile without errors, and hopefully run without making more errors down the line. You can use the `any` type to tell TypeScript to not type-check `saveData`.

```typescript
const saveData: any = {
    userPartyRoleId: Number(this.userPartyRoleId),
    notes: this.notes
};

saveData.speciality = this.spec;
```

With this solution, you will lose TypeScript's strict-typing feature, which is the point of TypeScript in the first place.